# Best method to find number of natural number solutions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For an equation,
                     ***a + b + c = D***

where D is a natural number and a, b, c are variables,
what is the quickest way to find the number of natural number solutions to this equation?

Comment: First, share with us one way you know to find the same.  Then we can better understand what might be quicker.

Comment: @amWhy That would be taking values from 1 to D - 2 for one of the variables and manually counting the possibilities for the the other two variables. For example.   when c = 1,   a + b = D - 1 , now I would count all possibilities for this, then take c = 2, and keep going until D - 2.

Answer (score 1):

Stars and bars.

The problem can be reformulated in the following way:

Suppose we have $D+2$ places where we want to put two bars and $D$ stars. Thus the number of solutions is $D+2 \choose 2$.